# tsCV (Time-Series Cross Validation) function not working in R

Tags: r, time-series, cross-validation, forecasting

I am trying to do a time series cross-validation to test the accuracy of some forecasting methods. I have the following code which defines a function *func_1* to compute forecasts of a dataset using an ETS model, and then test it using time-series cross validation:

```
library(fpp2)
library(fpp3)
library(forecast)

func_1 <- function(y, h){
  fc <- forecast(object = ets(y), h=h)
  return(fc)
}

tsCV(y = visitors, forecastfunction = func_1, h = 1)
```

The function *func_1*, when given appropriate arguments (y = univariate time series, h = forecasting horizon), works perfectly fine. However, when *func_1* is entered into the *tsCV* function as an argument to *forecastfunction*, R does not ouput anything, and instead just gets stuck. I read the documentation of *tsCV* and here is what I have about *forecastfunction*:

> **forecastfunction:**
> *Function to return an object of class forecast. Its first argument must be a univariate time series, and it must have an argument h for the forecast horizon.*

I believe my function meets this criteria, but it is still not working. However, the following code works just fine:

```
tsCV(y = visitors, forecastfunction = naive, h = 1)
```

The only difference is that *naive* is a function that is a part of the package *forecast* and was not created by me.

Answer (score 1):

The series `visitors` contains 240 observations, so there are approximately 240 training sets. For each one, `ets()` will estimate 15 models before identifying the best model. So that is 3600 nonlinear optimizations, involving up to 17 parameters each. It's going to take some time. On the other hand, `naive` does not require any optimization, so it is extremely fast.

Leave it for a few minutes and `tsCV()` using your function `func_1()` will return a result.